How do I connect a node.js API to a RabbitMQ instance on Fly.io?
See more: JavascriptNode.jsRabbitMQ
I have a project that I am trying to get connected to a rabbit mq broker that I have set up on fly.io with a node.js API, but I cannot figure out how to do this.
What I have tried:
I tried various ways of re-writing the url for the amqp connection, but none of these worked. Here is my rabbit mq url environment variable within my node.js api:
#----Service Dependency Variables----
RABIT_MQ_URL=amqp://rabbit-mq-fly-dep.fly.dev:5672
#----Service Dependency Variables----

I also tried this format:
#----Service Dependency Variables----
RABIT_MQ_URL=amqp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@rabbit-mq-fly-dep.fly.dev:5672/VHOST_NAME
#----Service Dependency Variables----

however, the error that I got in my node.js app is still the same:
ERR {
  success: false,
  message: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND rabbit-mq-fly-dep.fly.dev
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:120:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'rabbit-mq-fly-dep.fly.dev'
  }
}

I have been looking online at other resources, but I can't find anything that could help me. The docs didn't seem to be much help either unless you want to connect to a local host which is easy:
#---Service Dependency Variables----
RABIT_MQ_URL=amqp://locahost
#----Service Dependency Variables----

This works every time if I run a rabbit MQ instance locally, of course.
I should also address that I did try and add an IP address to the fly.io deployment and tweaked the url to use amqps insted of the amqp protocol in the node API's environment variables since the rabbit mq instance is set up to use TLS, but still got the same connection error. Here is the format of said implementation in the node.js API's variables:
#----Service Dependency Variables----
RABIT_MQ_URL=amqps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IPV6ADDRESS:5672/emailer
#----Service Dependency Variables----

I have no idea why this isn't working.
Here is my docker file for the fly.io rabbit mq instance:
FROM rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
COPY ./prod.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

and my fly.io toml file:
# fly.toml app configuration file generated for rabbit-mq-fly-dep on 2024-09-25T14:16:38-04:00
#
# See https://fly.io/docs/reference/configuration/ for information about how to use this file.
#

app = 'rabbit-mq-fly-dep'
primary_region = 'mia'

[build]

[[services]]
  protocol = "tcp"
  internal_port = 5672

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    interval = "15s"
    timeout = "1m0s"
    grace_period = "1s"

  [[services.ports]]
    port = 5673
    handlers = ["tls"]

[[services]]
  protocol = "tcp"
  internal_port = 15672

  [[services.ports]]
    port = 15672
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    interval = "15s"
    timeout = "1m0s"
    grace_period = "1s"

and here is the rabbit mq instance's .config file
listeners.tcp.default=5672
default_user=admin
default_pass=admin
management.tcp.ip=::

Any help on how to get this working would be much appreciated. Thanks!
